# importing packages using atom

Tags: java, import, ocr, atom-editor

I am new to java and I am trying to use an OCR library on atom. I have downloaded the Tess4J library and had placed it in my project folder. But I have no idea how to import it for atom doesn't have an "add library" option. I can use Eclipse but this is making me want to tear myself into pieces. 
This is the basic set up I have:

```
import java.io.File;
import net.sourceforge.tess4j;
import net.sourceforge.tess4j.TesseractException;
public class tess{
  public static void main (String [] args){

  }
}
```

After I ran this in terminal, it gives me the following error:

```
tess.java:3: error: package net.sourceforge does not exist
import net.sourceforge.tess4j;
                      ^
tess.java:4: error: package net.sourceforge.tess4j does not exist
import net.sourceforge.tess4j.TesseractException;
                             ^
2 errors
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you use Maven or Gradle?

If you use Maven, you can add this to your Pom file:
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.tess4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>tess4j</artifactId>
    <version>4.4.1</version>
</dependency>

Comment: Hi, I switched to Eclipse with Maven, and it worked. But I still can't get over the fact that I cannot use it in Atom. I have installed the package Atom-Maven, but it doesn't seem to have a pom.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

So as i wrote in the comment, if you add the following lines to your Pom file, your project should be able to find the imports you are trying to use thanks to Maven.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.tess4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>tess4j</artifactId>
    <version>4.4.1</version>
</dependency>
```

The fact that it still doesn't work in Atom, seems to be a Atom specific problem. I have no experience with Atom, so i can not really help you there.

You stated that you are new to Java and that you do not fancy Eclipse. I would suggest that you take a look in either Netbeans or IntelliJ. Netbeans, IntelliJ and Eclipse are the most common used Ide's for Java. It all comes down to personal preference, but at the beginning of your learning curve, using a common idea can really help you by preventing creating such ide specific questions on basic Java.